# Test Statistics

Tags: descriptive-statistics

My second question is about Test Statistics.

The questions and answers are on this PDF: http://www.mediafire.com/?b74e633lxdb49rb

I understand that they work out the join density and I know how to calculate this.

What I really don’t understand is how they figure out the test statistic. They randomly multiply by 1 in some cases and in some cases they just pick a sum. I don’t understand WHY that’s the test statistic - is it a guess?

Also, how do you check a test statistic you have calculated is correct?

Comment: Please invest some time in asking. "Please explain me this PDF that will disappear within a few weeks" is not making the Internet a better place. Thus I must close it in a current state.

Answer (score 2):

They don't randomly multiply by 1.  What they do is split the joint density into the product of two functions: $g(\text{sufficient statistic},\text{parameter})$ and $h(\text{data})$.

The advantage of $h()$ is that it removes sometimes complicated parts of the density function which provide no useful information about estimating the parameter. At other times this is unnecessary, in which case $h()$ can be set to 1 and ignored. In either case you can concentrate on the [sufficient statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic).